# How to delete all the data from the table in sqlplus oracle

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to delete all the data rows in the table, but without dropping the table. The delete statement has a where clause so I have to give one by one for each row. Is there any other way of deleting the whole data rows in the table?

This is `Oracle` and using `sqlplus`

Comment: The `WHERE` clause in SQL is completely optional.  So `DELETE FROM mytable;` is perfectly valid, and will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better that you drop constraint and then use Truncate command and after getting rid of data , apply the constraint again.

Answer (score 6):

You can try:
TRUNCATE TABLE tableName

Answer (score 4):

```
Truncate Table tablename
```

http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands

You can delete all records with `delete from tablename` also but truncate is much faster

Comment: I was just about to post this link. :-)

Comment: how to truncate when we have foreign keys. can someone help me

Comment: Well, that's different... :-) Should have mentioned that in your original question. You will need to drop the foreign key constraints then do the delete/truncate & add the constraint back.

Comment: in drop table there is something called cascase constraints. dont truncate have the same

Answer (score 1):

Try out Bulk deletion using [FORALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm). In that instead of deleting one row at time an entire bulk can be deleted in a single delete transaction.